# Nearest point to a convex polytope

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

I am looking for fast, memory-efficient computational algorithms to solve the following problem:

Minimize: $||x - x*||_2^2$, subject to constraints $A x = a, B x <= b, l <= x <= u$,

where $x*$ is given; $x, l, u, \in R^n$, $A \in R^{m x n}$, $B \in R^{p x n}$.  Note that `$n$' is very large, $O(10^4 to 10^6)$, and $m$ and $p$ are much smaller.  .

My problem is to project the point $x*$ onto the nearest feasible point, where feasible region is defined by the equality, inequality, and box constraints.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are willing to make the optimization function with $\|\cdot\|_1$ instead of $\|\cdot\|_2^2$, this would be linearizable, and you could do it with the Simplex algorithm or other similar algos.

Comment: Another special case: ignoring inequality constraints, this would become a regular least squares problem, also polynomial time. I think in the most general formulation, your quadratic programming problem is NP-hard...

Comment: Yes I know that if I ignored inequality constraints, I can solve the simple least-squares problem.  This suggests an iterative procedure to me. Suppose I ignore the box constraints.  For a given x*, I turn the active inequality constraints into equality constraints (augment the corresponding rows of B to A), and solve the least squares problem. Now, if none of the inequality constraints are violated, I am done. If not, I add the violated constraints to equality constraints and repeat.  I don't know if this simple-minded procedure is guaranteed to converge in finite number of steps.

Comment: I would instead introduce slack variables for the constraints, to satisfy them with equality. That would allow you to absorb everything into $A$ and allow to utilize the least squared projection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of slack variables.  Suppose that I know replace my inequality thus:  Bx - z = b, where z > 0, and z in R^p.  Now, I have to find x and z.  How do I do this?  Do I have to modify my original objective function to also include z, the slack variables?

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve quadratic programming problems with interior point method. For example, there is an [Ipopt](https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt) package. This package can be used for any non-linear programming problems, though both objective and constraints must be differentiable.

In my case there were near $n = 10^4$ variables, and $O(n^2)$ constraints, and it worked about 1 min on my PC. Though, in your case, when $m$ and $p$ are much smaller, the required time may be smaller.